# React JS "npm start" shows failed to complile web-vitals

Tags: reactjs

```
failed to compile -/src/reportWebVitals.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'web-vitals'.
```

Since new to react JS, could not find what happened. Here is the `reportWebVitals.JS` file. Thanks in advance for the help.

> "/src/reportWebVitals.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'web-vitals' in 'E:\ReactResources\RectProjects\test-app\src'"`

Comment: `npm install web-vitals` ?

Answer (score 2):

In your Terminal stop the server (Ctrl+C) and run the following command:

`npm i web-vitals --save-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Manually installing web-vitals worked for me.
I used the following command

```
yarn add web-vitals
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to app.js, remove `import reportwebvitals`,
and at the end remove report web vitals.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).